# Prevent collapse of empty rows in HTML table via CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a HTML table as follows:

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Row with text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><!-- Empty row -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

When you run this you'll see the second row is collapsed, but I'd rather it was rendered uncollapsed, with the same height as the first row. One way of doing this is to put a `&nbsp;` entity, as follows:

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Row with text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td><!-- Empty row -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way I can achieve the second result, via CSS, using the HTML from the first snippet?

Comment: Just give a min-height to td via css.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
td:empty::after{
  content: "\00a0";
}
```

It adds **escaped** `&nbsp;` after every originally empty `td`, solving your issue.

```css
td:empty::after{
  content: "\00a0";
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Row with text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><!-- Empty row -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>asd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>dees</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><!-- Empty row -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

Learn more about escaping HTML entities [here](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/04/named-html-entities-in-numeric-order/).

Answer (score 4):

You can add [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) to table-cell, in this case it'll work like [min-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height) property for other elements (with `display: block`, `display: inline-block`, etc). I added another table row with long text to demonstrate it:

```css
td {
    height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Row with text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><!-- Empty row -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Very-very long text with many words, Very-very long text with many words, Very-very long text with many words, Very-very long text with many words, Very-very long text with many words</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can't use [min-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height) property, because [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-min-height) says:

> In CSS 2.1, the effect of 'min-height' and 'max-height' on tables, inline tables, table cells, table rows, and row groups is undefined.

Comment: This solution works, but it's not as good as wscourge's solution because, depending on what you set the height to, blank rows may not be exactly the same height as non-blank rows. With wscourge's solution blank and non-blank rows are the same height.

Comment: @DanStevens yes, I agree, his solution is better =).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your table CSS formatting like

```
table.someclass tbody td {
      white-space:nowrap;
      min-width:30px;
      vertical-align:top;
}
```

This will make all empty cells equal and at least 30px wide.

Things like `&nbsp;`, `nowrap` and CSS content appending like `content: "\00a0";` didn't work for me.