# HTML table with rows of input boxes, when no default value row is collapsed

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have  the following table with dynamically generated rows of input boxes which may contain  default value. When no default is available from the database an empty string is returned `''`. The problem is this causes the table to be collapsed on those inputs.

```
 <tr *ngFor="let d of displayData">
    <td class=".mytable"> {{d.specRow}} </td>
    <td *ngFor="let l of d.limitModel ">
      <input type="text" [ngModel]="l?.target" (ngModelChange)="changeSelectedItem($event, l)" [name]="l.target" />
    </td>
```

If I click in the input box next to `Comment 4` then more rows are added until the next input with an empty string is reached. The input is tied to a model - how can I force these rows to render with an empty string?

[image]

EDIT: When not bound with ngModel the rows load as expected. The issue is binding to an empty string.

Comment: try using `&nbsp;` (non breaking space) instead of an empty string.

Comment: Michel - maybe I'm dense here but when I try to use the non breaking space it's treated like a string by the interface and thus displays "&nbsp;" in the text box.

Comment: Ah, didn't take the interfaces into account. The [answer found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42225797/1685196) is in the css: `td:empty::after{
  content: "\00a0";
}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent collapse of empty rows in HTML table via CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225196/prevent-collapse-of-empty-rows-in-html-table-via-css)

Comment: I've tried all these methods out and they do modify the table but I still face the same problem where rows do not render properly on the screen, once i click around and they render then the CSS takes affect.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for your particular case would be to add a hide class to those rows that have empty data.

```html
 <tr *ngFor="let d of displayData" [class.hidden]="d.specRow == ''">
```

Ensure you have a corresponding 'hidden' class in your CSS.

Comment: I need to display the empty boxes as the user may want to add a value where one does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I did as a workaround. The rows would only render properly if each cell had value.

So I load the display with a `' '` in place of null for each empty input box. Afterwards I loop through all the inputs and trim after rendering is complete.

```
     this.displayData?.forEach((x) => {
      x.limitModel.forEach((y) => {
        y.target = y.target.trimStart();
      });
    });
```